# Javascript; selecting a nested element is throwing a "not a function" error

Tags: javascript

I need to select an element within another element (a button within a form).  I'd normally use jQuery; which would look something like this:

```
element = $('#webform-client-form-1812 input[name="op"]');
```

But I can't use jQuery on this project so I tried:

```
element = document.getElementById("webform-client-form-1812").getElementsByName("op")[0];
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementsByName is not a function.

This seems like one of those issues where the solution will be embarrassingly obvious to others.  But I've looked at this thoroughly and I can't spot my mistake.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByName` is only a method on `document` - unlike `getElementsByClassName`, it's not callable on individual elements.

Use `querySelector` instead, and you can use the same CSS selector you used in jQuery:

```
const element = document.querySelector('#webform-client-form-1812 input[name="op"]');
```

It's probably good to use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` instead of nested `getElement... getElement` calls whenever possible - it's less unnecessarily verbose and makes the code clearer. You can easily express a *lot* of complicated rules with a CSS selector string that would be quite unwieldy to code otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Because 'getElementsByName' and 'getElementById' can only supported by object 'document' and 'XMLDocument', you can compare with getElementByTagName.http://help.dottoro.com/ljlfpmux.php

Comment: So; getElementByTagName works differently than getElementsByName and getElementById?

Comment: Now you have known why it can not work, you can work around it by yourself,  and there are many ways to solve the problem,  and CertainPerformance have give you an answer